# Pass data to vue component

Tags: vue.js

i'm learning Vue.js right now, but i have a little problem on understanding a quite easy task ( maybe my idea of programming is too old ).
i've created a little component with this code.

```
<template>
    <div class="tabSelectorRoot">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(element,index) in elements" v-on:click="changeSelected(index)">
                <a :class="{ 'selected': activeIndex === index }" :data-value="element.value"> {{ element.text }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="indicator"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "TabSelectorComponent",
        data () {
            return {
                activeIndex : 0,
                elements: [
                    { 'text':'Images', 'value': 'immagini','selected':true},
                    { 'text':'WallArts', 'value': 'wallart'}
                ]
            }
        },
        created: function () {
        },
        methods: {
            'changeSelected' : function( index,evt) {
                if ( index == this.activeIndex) { return; }
                this.activeIndex = index;
                document.querySelector('.indicator').style.left= 90 * index +'px';
                this.$emit('tabSelector:nameChanged',)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and this is the root

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <tab-selector-component></tab-selector-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TabSelectorComponent from "./TabSelectorComponent";
export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {TabSelectorComponent},
    data () {
        return {
            msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
        }
    },
    'mounted' : function() {
        console.log(this)
        //EventManager.eventify(this,window.eventManager);
        /*this.register('tabSelector:changeValue',function(el){
            console.log(el);
        });*/
    }
}
</script>
```

All of this renders in something like this 
[image] 
I'd like to reuse the component by varying the number of objects inside the list but i cannot understand how to accomplish this simple task

Comment: Pass in the `elements` array as a `prop` of the `TabSelectorComponent`. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: @Bert you are right, thanks. Can you reply to the question instead of comment it so i can mark as accepted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic way to communicate between components in Vue is using properties and events. In your case, what you would want to do is add an `elements` property to your `TabSelectorComponent` that is set by the parent.

**TabSelectorComponent**

```
export default {
  name: "TabSelectorComponent",
  props: ["elements"],
  data () {
    return {
      activeIndex : 0
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

In your parent:

```
<tab-selector-component :elements="elementArray"></tab-selector-component>
```

This is covered in the [documentation here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

Comment: I've added to data just to be clear that the array is no longer needed there. Please review if it matches your intentions.